# Calculating an Exponent

Tags: php, excel, exponent

In Excel `=(B5/2)^2*3.141592654`, where **B5** is the rod.

This doesn't produce the same results.

```
$rodarea = $rod/2 ^2*3.141592654 ;
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My guess your error is in whatever language (perl?) this is written in:

`$rodarea = $rod/2 ^2*3.141592654 ;`

Many programming languages don't honor `^` as a exponent operator, due to ambiguity with `XOR` which is also `^`. They will typically have some function like `pow` or `exp` to do exponents. In your case you could also just do:

```
$rodarea = (($rod/2)*($rod/2))*3.141592654 ;
```

(Exponent in perl is `**`, not `^`, though I don't know if that's the right language).

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, ^ is an exponential operator.... in PHP, ^ is a bitwise operator. To calculate an exponential in PHP, you need to use the [pow()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) function.

```
$rodarea = pow($rod / 2, 2) * 3.141592654 ;
```